# SQLAlchemy ORM - define custom function in model for selects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I define custom filter function for model, so I won't duplicate it across my app?
I mean if I have some model, like this:

```
class DataTables(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'datatables'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    table_name = Column(String(50))
    row_id = Column(String(50))
    row_data = Column(BLOB)
```

and I often use such select (get row_data for specific table and row):

```
session.execute(select(DataTables.row_data).where(DataTables.table_name == table_name, DataTables.row_id == row_id))
```

I don't want to use ActiveRecord mixin, where i can get session inside model. So i want to make some function, which will get 2 params and return object for `session.execute`. I didn't find anything useful in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own session class that you can expand further for these operations like this:

```
class DataTablesSesssion:
    def __init__(session):
        self.session = session

    def get_row_data_by_name_and_row_id(table_name, row_id):
        return self.session.execute(
           select(DataTables.row_data)
           .where(
               DataTables.table_name == table_name, 
               DataTables.row_id == row_id
           )
        )
    
    def get_some_other_kind_of_data(some_variable):
        ...
```

Which you can then use in your code like

```
data_tables_session = DataTablesSession(session)
row_data = data_tables_session.get_row_data_by_name_and_row_id("name", 1)

some_other_kind_of_data = data_tables_session.get_some_other_kind_of_data(42)
```

As your application grows and you have more models and modules that use database connection, having this kind of session object for each module will give you good separation between your model and your database interaction code (this is how I use SQL Alchemy in a 30k LOC project and it works well to avoid duplication and spaghetti code).